# Is there any way to strongly type a controls Tag property?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have a TreeView control which displays two things:

```
1) Folder
2) Item
```

Where folders contain items.  And the root folder contains all subfolders as well as items that do not belong to a folder.

I have a `Folder` type associated with the nodes that represent folders and an `Item` type associated with the nodes that represent items.

Now, the user can select any node, and perform different actions.  I need to be able to distinguish between the types stored in the Tag property.  If this is not possible, what are my options for getting around this?

Comment: You can inherit from almost all of the WinForms controls and add whatever properties you wish. Originally, you were told do that in the first place. The `Tag` property was only added as a concession to VB 6 programmers who didn't understand OOP and in hopes of easing migration. In most cases, you should probably ignore it and add strongly-typed custom properties anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily make a typed tag if needed:

```
public class MyTreeNode<T> : TreeNode
{
    public T TypedTag { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Of course if you have two different types, then you have to cast the treenode back to the right form anyway, or add both types to the treenode and select on one or other being null.

Comment: @tyranid Actually, couldn't you implement two overloaded methods, one that takes a FolderTreeNode and one that takes an ItemTreeNode to process them correctly without having to cast?

Comment: Well I presume you want this for when the AfterSelect event fires (or similar). At that point all you would get is a TreeNode object reference, from which you would have to infer the "real" object type. You could overload the OnAfterSelect method to fire different events for different node types, but you are just pushing the problem somewhere else. Another alternative would be to define a standard interface with say a "DoAction" method which each type of TreeNode can implement then only cast to that interface type, but that might not be very flexible and doesn't really get around the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Use the 'as' and or 'is' operator? e.g.

```
if(node.Tag is Folder)
{
     Folder f = node.Tag as Folder;
}
else if (node.Tag is Item)
{
     ...
}
```